# IntelliJ IDEA Java Project Settings Dependencies Jar File Order lost on Restart

Tags: intellij-idea, module, jar, dependencies

I am using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition, for a Java project. There are several modules in the project. Each module has dependencies listed in the Dependencies tab of the Project Settings. It turns out that many of the modules rely on a jar file that I add to the dependencies list, but that I have to change the order of the dependencies for each module, so that the jar file I added goes lower down on the list. This works alright. However, when I restart the IDE, or maybe also when I change the version of Java using SDKMAN, the position of the jar file in the dependencies list is also reset, so that it appears at the top of the list. This means that every time I restart the IDE, I have to go through each module and update the dependency order for this one jar file. It takes about 20 minutes for me to update the modules this way, which is a big hassle. If I could simply click a button and have the jar file moved immediately to the end of the list that would be a big help, but that button doesnt exist. Is there a way to make it so that the order of dependencies isnt lost? In the .iml file it appears that the jar file is an OrderEntry of type "module-library", as opposed to other entries that are either "module" or "library". I don't want to update the .iml file directly if I can help it, as using the IDE gui is probably faster.

Comment: Is your project a Maven/Gradle project? In this case, try to change the library order in pom.xml/build.gradle to see if it helps. Also, any reason that you want to change the dependencies order?

Comment: HI @LJ replica, thanks for it. Actually, the jar file that I add to the module is not listed in the pom.xml file. Its purely through the IDE. I dont want to change the order of the dependencies coming from the pom file. I just need to change the order for the attached jar file, so that when the existing setup has a class definition, that is preferred over the attached jar file, but if the class is not otherwise found, it can get to it via the attached jar file.

Comment: I noticed something else today. This also happens when I change branches. For the modules that are affected by the branch change, the attached jar file goes back to the top of the dependencies list.

Comment: It's better to add that jar to your pom.xml in the correct order. The IDEA uses the Maven as the single source of truth and sometime it would reload the pom.xml to read the library's info which resets any change in the `Modules`. Also, when you change something in the `Modules`, it would show "Module xxx is imported from Maven. Any changes made in its configuration might be lost after reporting".

Comment: @LJ replica, Thanks, I dont want to list the jar file in the pom files, as that would affect other developers, who aren't using IntelliJ IDEA. I am one of the few developers using that IDE, so getting the projects to build in that IDE is basically my responsibility. I dont have a better way right now to include the definitions of the classes that are found in this jar file.